# stop program from exit/termination until user types exit

Tags: c#

```
{
Console.WriteLine("Whatever you type, You will get same Output");
string userValue;
userValue = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Your written Words Are: " + userValue);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have nothing wrong with the code except i don't want console to be close while user writes anything.
e.g. If user types ABC then console should say You typed ABC. The Program should ask Would you like to type more? If user writes Yes then Type again until user type Exit and then program should terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it in the loop, something like this:

```
string userValue;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Whatever you type, You will get same Output");
    userValue = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Your written Words Are: " + userValue);
}
while(userValue != "Exit");
```

Comment: The Program should ask Would you like to type more? If user writes Yes then Type again.

Comment: You should be able to make those changes yourself based on the information given.

Comment: do{
                Console.WriteLine("Whatever you type, You will get same Output");
                userValue = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your written Words Are: " + userValue);
            }
            while (userValue != "exit");
            Console.WriteLine("Would YOu like to Type More?");
            if (userValue == "Yes") ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Whatever you type, You will get same Output");
                userValue = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Your written Words Are: " + userValue);

Comment: It's not an infinite loop if it has an exit condition; it's just a loop.